# How to read Outlook emails without using Graph API using the email ID and password in Python?

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments

I cannot run my script locally using pywin32 - MAPI as it is to be hosted on a server/remote desktop without Outlook application installed on the machine.
Can you please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have Azure P2 subscription.
2. Look into the following link and get an app registered and assign permissions to the same. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/reading-o365-emails-from-daemon-process-using-graph-bhattacharya/
3. Create "Creds.py" file and add the credentisl - base_path, client_id, client_secret, object_id, scope, url_access_token, tenant_id, url_attachments, url_messages to it as strings to it. (refer the link above to understand what each of it means and how to get the values of them).

The following code checks if a particular string "body_tag" is present in the body of an email and then downloads all the attachments of that particular email if it is present. Also, it only reads the "unread" emails.

**CODE**

```
import requests
import base64
from Creds import base_path, client_id, client_secret, object_id, scope, url_access_token, tenant_id, url_attachments, url_messages
# Access Token
url_access_token = url_access_token.format(tenant_id)
body_tag = ""
payload = {
  'client_id': client_id,
  'scope': scope,
  'client_secret': client_secret,
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
files=[]
headers = {}
response = requests.request("POST", url_access_token, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
access_token = response.json()['access_token']
# Get Emails
url_messages = url_messages.format(object_id)
payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
}
response = requests.request("GET", url_messages, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
emails = response.json()['value']
for email in emails:
  body = email['body']
  if(body_tag in str(body)):
    message_id = ""
    if(email['hasAttachments']):
      message_id = email['id']
      # Get the attachments
      if(len(message_id) > 0):
        # Attachments
        url_attachments = url_attachments.format(object_id, message_id)
        response = requests.request("GET", url_attachments, headers=headers, data=payload)
        val = response.json()["value"]
        for i in range(len(val)):
          attachment_id = val[i]["id"]
          attachment_name = val[i]["name"]
          attachment_content_type = val[i]["contentType"]
          content_bytes = val[i]["contentBytes"]
          base64String = content_bytes
          with open(base_path+attachment_name, 'wb') as theFile:
            theFile.write(base64.b64decode(base64String))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with Exchange accounts only you may also consider using EWS, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.